Find the side lengths of a right triangle in terms of the distances of a point from its vertices,
I came up with a question a little while ago but it doesn't seem to me to be easy to solve

Consider the diagram shown in the image where $P$ is any point in the plane, can $A,B$, and $C$ be found in terms of $X,Y,Z$

Here's a synthetic approach:
We have, on center $P$, three circles with radii $X,Y,Z$. The question is whether we may construct a right triangle with a vertex on each circle.
The top row shows construction with the right angle on the inner circle: pick any point $A$ as the right angle, and draw perpendicular lines from that point. They must intersect the middle and outer circle, and we may rotate the perpendicular lines for a variety of solutions. This always has infinite solutions.
The second row shows construction with $A$ on the middle circle. Here, it is always possible to solve for qualifying triangles, for we simply set on of the perpendicular lines to be the tangent to the inner circle, and sweep inwards for an infinite set of solutions. However, it is in general going to be possible to orient the perpendicular lines so that the orientation produces no solution (final picture).

If we set $A$ to be on the outer circle, we obtain either $0$, $1$, or infinite solutions. If we place one of the perpendiculars as a tangent to the inner circle, the other perpendicular either does not intersect the middle circle (left pic), is tangent to the middle circle (second pic), or is a secant (third pic), corresponding to $0$, $1$, or infinite solutions.


To link the third scenario ($A$ on the outer circle) with @πρόσεχε 's answer, observe that the second perpendicular has distance $\sqrt{X^2 - Z^2}$ from the origin, so the three cases correspond to $Y^2 <{}$ or ${}={}$ or ${}>X^2 - Z^2$.  In the middle case, for $X^2 = Y^2 + Z^2$, there is a unique $\theta$ such that $Y = X \sin\theta$ and $Z = X \cos\theta$, i.e. $U=V=0$, etc.

If the vertices of the triangle and the point have coordinates:
$$
(0,0)\qquad(A,0)\qquad(0,B)\qquad(X\cos\theta,X\sin\theta)
$$
then the following two equations must be satisfied:
$$
\begin{cases}
Y^2=(X\cos\theta-A)^2+(X\sin\theta-0)^2\\
Z^2=(X\cos\theta-0)^2+(X\sin\theta-B)^2\\
\end{cases}.
$$
This system of equations doesn't admit real solutions if:
$$
U:=Y^2-X^2\sin^2\theta<0
\quad\text{or}\quad
V:=Z^2-X^2\cos^2\theta<0
$$
otherwise it admits four real solutions:
$$
(A,B)=(X\cos\theta-\sqrt{U},X\sin\theta\pm\sqrt{V})
\quad\text{or}\quad
(A,B)=(X\cos\theta+\sqrt{U},X\sin\theta\pm\sqrt{V}).
$$
In any case, $X,Y,Z$ aren't enough, you also need $\theta$.
